# ConfuserEx CLI run but no output result

Tags: .net, obfuscation, confuserex

I have `crproj` file and there is setup for confuser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project baseDir="C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers" outputDir="C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers\ConfuserTest" xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
    <rule preset="normal" pattern="true">
        <protection id="anti debug" />
        <protection id="anti dump" />
        <protection id="anti ildasm" />
        <protection id="anti tamper" />
        <protection id="constants" />
        <protection id="ctrl flow" />
        <protection id="invalid metadata" />
        <protection id="ref proxy" />
        <protection id="rename" />
        <protection id="resources" />
    </rule>
    
</project>
```

I am running it in pre-build config:

`if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "ReleaseDC" $(SolutionDir)Installers\ConfuserEx\Confuser.CLI.exe $(ProjectDir)Confuser.crproj`

Execution is successfull, but there is no output folder with result. Also, when I add some modules `<module> path</module>` I get following error `Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The command "REM Delete and recreate source folder

```
  if exist "C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers\FilesToPackageDC\ReleaseDC" rd "C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers\FilesToPackageDC\ReleaseDC" /s /q
  md "C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers\FilesToPackageDC\ReleaseDC"

  REM Copy ChangeNotes.txt
  xcopy /i /q /y /c "C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\ChangeNotes.txt" "C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers\FilesToPackageDC\ReleaseDC\"
 if "ReleaseDC" == "ReleaseDC" C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers\ConfuserEx\Confuser.CLI.exe C:\Users\sserbula\Desktop\Projects\telexis\TSU\Installers\Telexis.DC.Installer\Confuser.crproj" exited with code 1.    Telexis.DC.Installer    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets   779
```

So I am stuck and documentation isn't helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem was in fact that `baseDir` doesn't have valid path. `BaseDir` should be path to folder where DLLs are and output where obfuscated DLLs should be.
And it couldn't be executed in pre-build script, only post-build